# Is there an equivalent in Python's unittest to Ncover's explicit attribute?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a file, full of unit tests. I want to add a test that will only run if it's manually selected, similar to NCover's Explicit attribute.

I suspect this involves the skipIf decorator, but I don't see what to check against. Through debugging, I can see that some of the unittest classes hold this info, but it's not passed to my code.

So far, I see two ways to sort of do this:
1) Have setUp() increment a counter per test. If the test is not the first one, skip. This is close, but means I need to be careful about the name to keep it from being run first.

2) Put a flag in the file, and check against it. The main problem is that involves code changes whenever I want to run the test, with all that implies.